# Hive Insert Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE

Tags: hive

I have created a table called example in Hive.

```
 CREATE TABLE example (id INT, name STRING, number STRING);
```

But there is an error like below when trying to insert some parameters.

```
 Insert into table example values (1,'Sample Data','1234123412341234')
```

> 18/04/30 13:26:46 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-40]: WARN
>   security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root
>   (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
>   Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:279)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:260)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:240)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:162)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:152)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:3877)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:3860)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:3842)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6762)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:4503)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4473)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4446)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:882)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.mkdirs(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:326)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:640)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

```
# su - hdfs

$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/root

$ hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/root

$ exit
```